# How To Get A List Displaying in React

Tags: reactjs, list

I'm trying to display a list of product features from some local JSON data using React, but my map/list functionality isn't displaying anything onto the DOM.

I originally had imported react-render-html, but it wasn't compatible so I had to remove it.

Here's my `productHighlights`:

```
class ProductHighlights extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                data: null
            }
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        const index = newProps.selected;
        const productData = Number.isInteger(index) ? newProps.productData[index] : null;
            if (productData !== null) {
                this.setState({ data: productData });
            }
        }

    getFeatureList = (itemDescription) => {
     itemDescription[0].features.map((feature, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{feature}</li>
        ))
      }

    render() {
        const itemDescription = this.state.data ? this.state.data.ItemDescription : null;
        const featureList = itemDescription ? this.getFeatureList(itemDescription) : null;
        console.log(itemDescription);
        console.log('item description = ' + itemDescription);

        return (
            <div className="product-highlights-container">
              <div className="product-highlights-title">product highlights</div>
              <ul className="product-features">
                {featureList}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )
    }
}

export default ProductHighlights;
```

Logging `itemDescription` to the screen shows `[{...}]`, which then opens to > `0` > 'features: Array(10)`. I'm not sure why`getFeaturedList` isn't getting this info successfully.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you. It's difficult to say what might be wrong without seeing how the props given to `ProductHighlights` look like.

Comment: `featureList` is `null`. That means your `data` looks slightly differently that you think.

Comment: @Sulthan Updated my post as I've narrowed it down

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message you are getting in the console?
Your map is implicitly returning undefined. You need to return the element.

```
itemDescription[0].features.map((feature, index) => 
  {
    return (<li key={index}>{feature}</li>);
  }
)
```

Comment: The only error message I get is `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.` and I don't think it relates to the code we're talking about

Comment: I console logged `itemDescription` and it's returning undefined, I'll have to see why it doesn't have any value

Answer (score -1):

I got it to display - all I had to do was add spaces around `feature` in this line in my `getFeatureList` function:

`<li key={index}>{ feature }</li>`

Only thing now is that the  tags are displaying in the list. I may need to parse.